# Reading from a UNIX domain socket (QLocalSocket) on Qt

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, unix-socket, qtnetwork

I am having trouble reading from a UNIX domain socket, server application is Python-based, and I need to implement IPC to communicate to Qt application as client. Server application is tested and working with a Python client application. Here is what I have on the Qt-client side:

**unixsocket.cpp**

```
#include "unixsocket.h"
#include <stdio.h>

UnixSocket::UnixSocket(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    this->socket = new QLocalSocket (this);
}

UnixSocket::~UnixSocket(){}

void UnixSocket::Test ()
{
    connect (this->socket, SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(connected_callback()));
    connect (this->socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(disconnected_callback()));
    connect (this->socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyRead_callback()));
    connect (this->socket, SIGNAL(bytesWritten(qint64)), this, SLOT(bytesWritten_callback(qint64)));

    qDebug() << "Connecting...";

    socket->connectToServer(ADAPTER_SOCKET);

    if (!socket->waitForConnected(1000))
    {
        qDebug() << "Error: " << this->socket->errorString();
    }
    else
    {
        in.setDevice(socket);
        in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_8);
        this->blockSize = 0;

    }

}

void UnixSocket::connected_callback()
{
    qDebug() << "Connected to " << socket->fullServerName();

}

void UnixSocket::disconnected_callback()
{
    qDebug() << "Disconnected!";
}

void UnixSocket::bytesWritten_callback(qint64 bytes)
{
    qDebug() << "We wrote: " << bytes;
}

void UnixSocket::readyRead_callback()
{
    qDebug() << "Reading...";
    qDebug() << "Block Size: " << this->blockSize;

    if (this->blockSize == 0) {
        // Relies on the fact that QDataStream serializes a quint32 into
        // sizeof(quint32) bytes
        if (socket->bytesAvailable() < (int)sizeof(quint32))
            return;
        in >> this->blockSize;
    }

    if (socket->bytesAvailable() < this->blockSize || in.atEnd())
        return;

    QString recvd_data;
    in >> recvd_data;
    qDebug() << recvd_data;
}
```

**unixsocket.h**

```
#ifndef UNIXSOCKET_H
#define UNIXSOCKET_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QAbstractSocket>
#include <QLocalSocket>
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QIODevice>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QDataStream>

#define ADAPTER_SOCKET "/opt/adapter/socket"


class UnixSocket: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit UnixSocket(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~UnixSocket();
    void Test ();

signals:

public slots:

    void connected_callback();
    void disconnected_callback();
    void bytesWritten_callback (qint64 bytes);
    void readyRead_callback();

private:
    QLocalSocket *socket;
    QDataStream in;
    quint32 blockSize;
};

#endif // UNIXSOCKET_H
```

and **main.cpp** to fire class:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    UnixSocket mUnixSocket;
    mUnixSocket.Test();
    while (1);
    return 1;
}
```

Now, the Unix Domain Socket connection is working fine. So, I get "connected" message. And I am sure the server is sending some data asynchronously, but my program does not enter `readyRead_callback` at all for some reason. I need pointers as to how to fix this problem. Any help is greately appreciated.

Comment: Does it work without threads?

Comment: Unfortunately not, already tested it by moving socket instantiation to main

Comment: then the problem is not caused by the threads, so I recommend you simplify your example by eliminating the thread.

Comment: Done, thanks for suggesting

Comment: change your main to `int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    UnixSocket mUnixSocket;
    mUnixSocket.Test();
    return a.exec();
}` do not use while(1) since it is blocking and the signals need the Qt event-loop.

Comment: Could you create and answer so that we can discuss there, this works, I want to upvote it. But it still does not work with thread. I'm wondering why.

Comment: I already published an answer, on the other hand I recommend **adding** as an update the use of threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [qt-signals](/questions/tagged/qt-signals) need to live in the Qt event loop, and in your case you do not have any, so it does not work for you, so change your code to:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    UnixSocket mUnixSocket; 
    mUnixSocket.Test(); 
    return a.exec(); 
}
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why it does not work inside a thread?, leaving QCoreApplication parts intact.

Comment: @mozcelikors I find it strange, it should work, but I have another question, why do you want to run it in a thread? The magic of the signals is that you avoid using threads to have asynchronous tasks.

Comment: That's very true. I was just now thinking if I really needed a thread, doing all this with signal/slot. I guess my previous thought process did not involve using signal/slot, thats why I fixated on the thread. So I can dig deeper using how it is currently. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @mozcelikors In Qt the last thing you need is the threads if the tasks are light, Qt offers tools to work asynchronously, that's their magic.

Comment: @mozcelikors in C++ use `#include <cstdio>` instead of `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: This was just a mock up code, so did not really pay attention. Will definitely use qDebug at the very last

Answer (score 0):

how to listen unix domain socket in server?
use `QLocalServer`, but `onNewConnection` not called

```
mServer = new QLocalServer;
connect(mServer, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(onNewConnection()));
```